# linking cinema 4d R20 file assets to cinema 4d R21

Tags: cinema-4d

is there a way to link cinema 4d R20 asset files (materials and other content packs) to cinema 4d R21 without copying or downloading it again in cinema 4d R21 as i have already did it in cinema 4d R20. Thank's alot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way.
Just look on your harddrive for the *.lib4D Files, if you built your own set of materials, you can export it before from cinema 4D as a Set; 
I guess your files are under "application folder" inside the "library/browser/ " - directory; (there's a second place where it could be stored if you type "%appdata% into your Windows-Explorer, but in general it would be in the application folder/cinema 4D R20/library/browser)

Now just copy them into the same place in Cinema 4D R21/library/browser.
That's it :-)

If you just want to "link" it like you said, under your preferences you can define where your materials are stored
There are different similar ways, as I know there is a possibility to do that via CommandLine 
(in R16/R17 I know, you could also change a config file (resource\config.txt) to change the path; I am not sure if this is still working but I will have a try when I am at home)